# Simplifying $F(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{2/(2-p)},1-p^2/4)$ (for a minimal surface)

Tags: elliptic-integrals, minimal-surfaces

The *tetragonal distortion* of the Schwarz P minimal surface has a Weierstrass–Enneper parametrisation of $g(w)=w,f(w)=(w^8+\lambda w^4+1)^{-1/2}$ and a Bonnet angle of $\pi/2$ where $\lambda<-2$. This surface can be decomposed into "catenoids" between square rings:

[image]

I have [worked out](https://gitlab.com/parclytaxel/Malibu/-/blob/19c599f3c9529c9fd4a9bb5d9cfa7dd2b12b46d2/malibu/minimal/schwarzt.py#L96-103) that the aspect ratio (height over base side) of this catenoid is $\sqrt{-ps}\frac ZX$ where
$$p=\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda^2-4},s=\sqrt{2-\lambda}$$
$$X=K\left(\frac12+\frac1s\right)$$
$$Z=F\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac2{2-p}},1-\frac{p^2}4\right)$$
(Here the last argument of elliptic integrals is the parameter $m$.)

I am unable to simplify $Z$ to a *complete* elliptic integral – I think it can be done, since the formula for the aspect ratio of the unit cell of the conjugate T (tetragonal D) surface only involves complete integrals. Can simplification on $Z$ be done?

In particular, can the Landen and Gauss transformations be applied to $Z$ to reduce it?

Comment: Let $m = 1 - p^2/4$, $x_0 = \sqrt {2/(2 - p)}$, then
$$\int_0^{x_0} \frac {dx} {\sqrt {(1 - x^2) (1 - m x^2)}} =
\frac 1 2 \int_0^1 \frac {dx} {\sqrt {(1 - x^2) (1 - m x^2)}}$$
(the reason is that we have the relation $m x_0^4 - 2 x_0^2 + 1 = 0$). This can be derived from the double angle formula for $\operatorname {sn}$ or geometrically as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3887493) by taking $x = u/(u + 1)$ and showing  that the tangent to the cubic curve at a point with $u = u(x_0)$ intersects the curve at a point with $u = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Carlson symmetric form:
$$Z=F\left(\sin^{-1}\sqrt{\frac2{2-p}},1-\frac{p^2}4\right)=\sqrt{\frac2{2-p}}R_F\left(\frac p{p-2},-\frac p2,1\right)$$
Now apply a descending Landen transformation ([DLMF 19.22.18, .23](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.22)) to get a zero as one argument, then scale to make another argument one:
$$=\sqrt{\frac2{2-p}}R_F\left(0,\frac{4p}{p-2},\frac{2-p}2\right)=\frac2{2-p}R_F\left(0,\frac{-8p}{(2-p)^2},1\right)$$
$R_F$ may now be converted back into a complete Legendre elliptic integral. Its parameter is quite complicated in $p$ alone, but substituting its definition $p=\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda^2-4}$ gives a surprisingly simple result:
$$\boxed{Z=\frac2{2-p}K\left(1+\frac{8p}{(2-p)^2}\right)=\frac2{2-p}K\left(\frac{\lambda+2}{\lambda-2}\right)}$$

---

$K(p^2/4)$ where $p$ has the same meaning appears in the T surface's aspect ratio formula. By the same approach as detailed above, but using an ascending Gauss transformation, I was able to simplify it to $\frac2{2-p}K\left(\frac4{2-\lambda}\right)$.